# How to use GNU sed on Eclipse in MacOS?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos-sierra

I use Eclipse Oxygen in Mac OS Sierra.
I want to run `sed` command on my Java code. The code is originally for Linux, so I installed GNU `sed` by `brew install gnu-sed --with-default-names`.
But the code works different from I expected, and I found the PATH variable is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. My GNU `sed` is installed in `/usr/local/bin`, but Eclipse seems to continue using `/usr/bin/sed`.

I tried to add it to PATH at `Run Configurations -> Environment`, but the code performs same as before.
I can use GNU `sed` on my local terminals(zsh/bash/sh) without any problem. But how can I use it on Eclipse?

[image]

Comment: I don't get it.  Are you trying to run `sed` from a Java program?  Or on a Java program?  And if the latter, why are you trying to do it from within Eclipse?  And if the problem is that `sed` is not on the PATH, why don't you just use the full pathname for the `sed` command?

Comment: Shame I didn't have that idea. Succeeded by using full pathname. Thanks!

Comment: If you updated your question to answer the questions that I asked ... someone might give you an answer.